# Printing characters on the same line after iterating through a string to eliminate punctuation

Tags: python

I am trying to print this all on the same line.  Currently, it iterates and prints each element on a single line.  I am trying to concatenate this back together onto a single line just as it was before

In:

```
def commaRip(hold):

    for i in hold:
        if i == ",":
            continue
        else:
            print(i)
```

Test:

```
commaRip("H,e,y, h,o,w, are you")
```

Out:

```
H

e

y
 
h

o

w
 
a

r

e
 
y

o

u
```

Comment: try `print(i, end=" ")`

Comment: This is a very basic python question. Maybe you want to check some tutorials. There are many good ones on the web.

Answer (score 2):

A newline is, by default, added to the end of string in print statement. To override this default, you can use this in the print statement:

```
print(i, end='')
```

The above code overrides the default of '\n' to '' in the print statement

Answer (score 1):

change `print(i)` to

```
print(i, end='')
```